# pandas fillna() not working properly

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to build a simple function to fill the pandas columns with 
some distribution, but it fails to fill the whole table (df still have NaN after fillna ...)

```
def simple_impute_missing(df):
    from numpy.random import normal
    rnd_filled = pd.DataFrame( {c : normal(df[c].mean(), df[c].std(), len(df))
                                  for c in df.columns[3:]})

    filled_df = df.fillna(rnd_filled)       
    return filled_df
```

**But the returned df, still have NaNs !**

I have checked to make sure that rnd_filled is full and have the right shape.
what is going on?

Comment: Are NaN in first, second and third column only?

Comment: if need replace NaN in all df, remove `[:3]` from `df.columns[3:]`

Comment: another possible problem is if all data in some column are `NaN`. Can you add data sample?

Comment: well columns 0..3 are just strings. there is not columns with only Nans

Comment: Hmmm, without data it is problematic, can you try my sample data or try change it for your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need remove `[:3]` from `df.columns[3:]` for select all columns of `df`.

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,np.nan,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[np.nan,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,np.nan],
                   'E':[5,np.nan,6],
                   'F':[7,np.nan,3]})

print (df)
     A  B    C    D    E    F
0  1.0  4  NaN  1.0  5.0  7.0
1  NaN  5  8.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
2  3.0  6  9.0  NaN  6.0  3.0

rnd_filled = pd.DataFrame( {c : normal(df[c].mean(), df[c].std(), len(df))
                                  for c in df.columns})

filled_df = df.fillna(rnd_filled)       
print (filled_df)
          A  B         C         D         E         F
0  1.000000  4  6.922458  1.000000  5.000000  7.000000
1  2.277218  5  8.000000  3.000000  5.714767  6.245759
2  3.000000  6  9.000000  0.119522  6.000000  3.000000
```